# Java number sorting algorithm - remove ugly break

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have written a little number sorting algorithm that puts a random array of integers into ascending order, my code is below and it is working fine. However there is the very ugly and unsatisfying break at lines 42 to 44. I would love some advice on how to get rid of that. I had to put this break in there to prevent overflow errors when the index goes into negative numbers. I am sure I can avoid this by looking at the algorithm from another angle but at the moment I just cant see it.

```
package algorithms;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class will place any list of numbers in numerical order
 * @author Richard
 *
 */
public class SortNumbers {

/**
 * This method will take a random set of numbers and
 * place them in numerical order
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //create array
    int[] numbers = new int[]{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,10,11,15,14};

    //find length of array to control loop
    int length = numbers.length-1; 

    //do not exceed length of array in loop
    for (int outer = 0; outer<length; outer++){

        //reset second counter
        int inner = 0;

        //keep looping while two consecutive numbers are not in order
        while (numbers[outer+inner]>numbers[outer+inner+1]) {

            //swap numbers that are not in order
            int temp = numbers[outer+inner];
            numbers[outer+inner] = numbers[outer+inner+1];
            numbers[outer+inner+1] = temp;

            //decrement and see if numbers need swapped again
            inner--;

            //break on negative index to prevent overflow error
            if (outer+inner<0) {
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    //convert finished array to string and print
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

}

}
```

Comment: If this was Code Review, I might answer. An alternative to a two-part termination condition as shown by mdfst13 in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/178493/93149) is planting a *sentinel*: find the first minimum, shift up elements before by one place, put minimum at index 0  and don't bother with "running off the low end of the array" ever after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     //find length of array to control loop
>     int length = numbers.length-1; 
>
>     //do not exceed length of array in loop
>     for (int outer = 0; outer<length; outer++){
>
>         //reset second counter
>         int inner = 0;
>
>         //keep looping while two consecutive numbers are not in order
>         while (numbers[outer+inner]>numbers[outer+inner+1]) {
>
>             //swap numbers that are not in order
>             int temp = numbers[outer+inner];
>             numbers[outer+inner] = numbers[outer+inner+1];
>             numbers[outer+inner+1] = temp;
>
>             //decrement and see if numbers need swapped again
>             inner--;
>
>             //break on negative index to prevent overflow error
>             if (outer+inner<0) {
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Consider

```
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // insert the ith element in its correct position among the elements up to i
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j]; j--) {
            int temp = numbers[j - 1];
            numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Rather than calculate `inner + outer`, we just track one value, which we call `j`.  Because we set it to the value of `i`, it will have the same values as `inner + outer` had in the original.

By moving the check for negative values into the loop control, we don't have to `break`.  We do end up doing an extra check because of that.

I prefer more horizontal whitespace to break up each line into more easily readable pieces.

I reduced the comments down to just one, which I believe is the only line that actually requires thinking to read.  I tried to explain the goal of that section of code rather than simply restate what the code does.

Incidentally, this algorithm is called an insertion sort.  It's one of the \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ sorts.  The built-in sort that Java uses is capable of \$\mathcal{O}(n\log n)\$ complexity.  You would normally only use an insertion sort for small input sizes.  For any decent sized input, a loglinear sort like quicksort or mergesort would be faster.  Of course, you may be [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) on purpose, for learning purposes.  When you do that, including the tag can better focus feedback.